# Stop loading page watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

Is there a way to stop loading a page with watir-webdriver on firefox? Or is there a way to force something in my script even if the page is still loading? At a point in my script, the website will hang and the script eventually timeouts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Timeout class to force it to give up after waiting a reasonable amount of time (and this is internally how Watir performs it's waits as well)

```
begin
  Timeout::timeout(10) do
    # perform actions that may hang here
  end
rescue Timeout::Error => msg
  put "Recovered from Timeout"
end
```

Comment: watir 6.7, the timeout will quit execution, but not stop the page loading. It will still wait for page loading finished to response any of my directive.

Answer (score 2):

If the website hangs, you should be able to use a wait method to timeout the script if an element does not appear.  These are mainly used as an answer to AJAX, but they should work for this condition as well.  For example, if the script hangs after you click a link, and you expect the next page to have a specific title or text:

```
@browser.link(:name => "Let's Hang!").click
Watir::Wait.until(30) { @browser.title == "new page" }
```

or

```
Watir::Wait.until(30) { @browser.text.include? ("confirmation text") }
```

or

```
@browser.image(:src => "awesome.jpg").wait_until_present(30)
```

Each of these will wait 30 seconds for the condition to be met before exiting with an error.  You can change the time (30) to exit within your app's hang window.

Comment: I don't think this will work, as if the page load that's being triggered never finishes the test will not progress to the point where a Wait can begin.

Comment: Does anyone have a site with a page that isn't currently loading to test?

Comment: could you perhaps use click_no_wait instead of click?

Comment: I've sometimes used yanking your network connection as a way to simulate a site that will not load, the trick is timing it just right so that you start to get data from the site and then it can't get the rest of the page.

Answer (score 1):

please have a look at the Selenium issue http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=687 it's not fixed yet, watir-webdriver is also based on Selenium, hope it answers your question.