# Getting Watir to wait until all 3rd party scripts have loaded

Tags: css, ruby, rspec, watir, watir-webdriver

### The Issue

Since changing some CSS to load in a font from Googlefonts I have found that occasionally when ran locally our Watir tests will fail because they are waiting for Googlefonts to load and our connection has hung or is just taking its time.

Because this is a CSS loading issue, all the elements of the page are accessible, so I can't use something like `wait_until_present` because the stuff is present, but Watir for whatever reason doesn't want to play with it.

I don't want to change my asset pipeline to not load in these things when testing locally, because that defeats the purpose of a sanity test.

### What I have tried

I have tried passing in something like;

```
browser.wait.until do
  window_loaded = browser.execute_script '$(window).load(function() { return true; });'
  window_loaded == true
end
```

But I couldn't get this to work, and I am not convinced this would be the correct way to solve this problem anyway.

Comment: What problems are you exactly seeing in the first place?

Comment: That Watir refuses to act on elements even though they are in the DOM, I think it is because it is waiting on these third party connections.

Comment: Show use the code you're using and which throws error and which error is thrown. It seems to me that you think that the element is in DOM, but in reality it isn't. It might be, for example, that Watir tries to access that element before it is in the DOM. What happens if you use the different waiting functions?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from: http://watirwebdriver.com/waiting/

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.start 'bit.ly/watir-webdriver-demo'
b.select_list(:id => 'entry_1').wait_until_present
b.text_field(:id => 'entry_0').when_present.set 'your name'
b.button(:value => 'Submit').click
b.button(:value => 'Submit').wait_while_present
Watir::Wait.until { b.text.include? 'Thank you' }
```

you could also use:

```
sleep 2
```

I personally use `sleep` to wait until everything is loaded. Works really well with AJAX.

Comment: I had considered using sleep, but it is far too brittle - if the internet connection hangs for 10 seconds I would need to set it for 11 seconds, which is fine but then when the connection is 100% my test will take 11 seconds extra to run for no reason.

Comment: Yup, agreed - do not use `sleep` ever in your tests. It is really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9539221/4817209).

```
begin
  Timeout::timeout(10) do
    # perform actions that may hang here
  end
rescue Timeout::Error => msg
  put "Recovered from Timeout"
end
```