# Watir webdriver - click an element and not wait for load

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

I have 2 sides in my page, clicking one of the buttons on the left side, refreshes the right side. 
Now I want to see whether the site gets stuck if i click the buttons too fast while not letting the right side to fully load.

Right now watir waits for the click command to return, so the test doesnt do what it should:

```
arr = ["div1", "div2", "div3"]
for i in 1..20 
    print "#{i}\r"
    choise = arr.sample
    b.div(:id=>choise).click
end
```

Any way to make it send the command and return without any delays?

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting the same result in multiple browsers?

The spec (which may or may not be implemented or implemented the same way by the different browsers), says that [webdriver prevents other commands from being executed while there are outstanding network requests](http://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#page-load-strategies-1). Though, it also says it should wait for document.readyState to be present for the frame currently handling the commands, so it is unclear if the outstanding network request is supposed to apply to only the current frame or to all frames.

But since Webdriver is designed for [commands to be handled in a synchronous manner](http://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#h3_detecting-when-to-handle-commands), it is likely just not designed to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you can try with javascripts:

```
@browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('choise').click")
```

Answer (score 0):

`b.div(:id => 'choise').exist?` - to check exist it or aren't

```
b.div(:id => 'choise').click
```

Answer (score -1):

I think [titusfortner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28968957/4817209) is right. But look [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9539221/4817209).

```
begin
  Timeout::timeout(10) do
    # perform actions that may hang here
  end
rescue Timeout::Error => msg
  put "Recovered from Timeout"
end
```